# Passing a Class as a parameter

Tags: c#

I have specific classes that I want to pass into an a method and I want to use that class in the method and return a version of that class.

```
protected Type [] Convert(ArrayList list, MyPersonalClass)
{
    MyPersonalClass[] resArray = (MyPersonalClass[])list.ToArray(typeof(MyPersonalClass));
    return resArray;
}
```

Comment: You want to use LINQ Cast<type>. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: 1.You can't pass `class` as a parameter, you can pass instances. 2.Don't use `ArrayList` use `List<T>` instead. 3. Your code won't compile for at least 2 reasons.

Comment: Have you looked into generic methods? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Comment: You cannot convert one class to another that easy. You should make custom converters to do that for your custom classes. And I didn't get what you want as return type. Look into `IConvertible` interface.

Comment: To send classes into methods the template parameters(`<T>`) are used. Just to let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) for this, so to directly convert your example:

```
public T[] Convert<T>(ArrayList list)
{
    return (T[])list.ToArray(typeof(T));
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
Convert<MyPersonalClass>(l);
```

The problem with doing it this way is that there is no way to guarantee the objects in the ArrayList are castable to `MyPersonalClass`.

Instead you might be better off using a generic list of `MyPersonalClass` and then you can just call `ToArray()` on that if you need an array:

```
List<MyPersonalClass> list = new List<MyPersonalClass>();
list.Add(new MyPersonalClass());

var arr = list.ToArray();
```